# Keras - Regularization & custom loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have built a custom Keras model which consists of various layers. Since I wanted to add L2 regularization to such layers, I've passed an instance of `keras.regularizers.l2` as the argument for the `kernel_regularizer` parameter of those layers (as an example, see the constructor of [`keras.layers.Conv2D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D)). Now, if I were to train this model using, say, Keras's implementation of the binary cross-entropy loss ([`keras.losses.BinaryCrossEntropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy)), I would be sure that the L2 regularization that I've specified would be taken into consideration when computing the loss.

In my case, however, I have a custom loss function that requires several other parameters aside from `y_true` and `y_pred`, meaning that there's no way I can pass this function as the argument for the `loss` parameter of `model.compile(...)` (in fact, I don't even call `model.compile(...)`). As a result, I also had to write a custom training loop. In other words, instead of simply running `model.fit(...)`, I had to:

1. Perform forward propagation by calling `model(x)`
2. Compute the loss
3. Compute the gradients of the loss with respect to the model's weights (that is, `model.trainable_variables`) with `tf.GradientTape`
4. Apply the gradients
5. Repeat

My question is: in which phase is regularization accounted for?

- During forward propagation?
- During the computation/application of the gradients?

Keep in mind that my custom loss function does NOT account for regularization, so if it's not accounted for in any of the two phases I've mentioned above, then I'm actually training a model with no regularization whatsoever (even though I've provided a value for the `kernel_regularizer` argument in each layer that my network is made of). In that case, would I be forced to compute the regularization term by hand and add it to the loss?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Comment: Please see the NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) (applicable also to DL questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regularization losses are computed on the forward pass of the model, and their gradients are applied on the backward pass. I don't think that your training step is applying any weight regularization, and consequently your model isn't regularized. One way to check this would be to actually look at the weights of a trained model - if they're sparse, it means you've regularized the weights in some way. L1 regularization will actually push some weights to 0. L2 regularization does a similar thing, but often results in less sparse weights.

[This](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/) post outlines writing a training loop from scratch in Keras and has a section on model regularization. The author adds the loss from regularization layers in his training step with the following command:

```
loss += sum(model.losses)
```

I think this may be what you need. If you are still unsure, I would train a model with the line above in the training loop, and another model without that line. Inspecting the weights of the trained models will give you some input on whether or not the weight regularization is working as expected.

Comment: So basically there must be a similar line of code in the implementation of Keras's fit(...) method, right?

Comment: Yes. See this line of code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L749. The code explicitly states regularization_losses = self.losses. Did the solution I posted above work?